# Как получить пересылаемое сообщение, имея обычное?

Tags: python, discord.py, python-3.9

Задача такая: Получить пересылаемое сообщение. То есть допустим я пересылаю сообщение пользователя X и пишу сообщение: "Abcd". При обращении к обьекту message.content, я получу своё сообщение, но как мне получить сообщение пользователя X?
Для написания бота использую класс discord.Client().
Вот фрагмент того что я успел написать:

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
        return
    if message.content.lower() == "!w_cd":
        referenced_message = message.to_reference()
        reference_message_content = referenced_message.content
        author_name = referenced_message.author.name
        author_url = referenced_message.author.avatar_url

        print(reference_message_content)
        print(author_url)
        print(author_name)

client.run(token)
```